# Paypal checkout with node.js - modules?

Tags: node.js, paypal

I want to do a checkout with PayPal for my little shop implemented in node. I have looked up modules on npm that would help with that (https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=paypal+checkout) but I'm not sure which one to pick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Express Checkout.  At first glance [this one](https://www.npmjs.org/package/paypal-ec) looks to be the best available.